# JavaScript files will not load into my Laravel Application on Dev Server

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Laravel Dev Application is not loading JavaScript

I am having a strange issue that I have never had before.  This is my first Laravel application I have done.  Anyways if you view the image below you will see my issue.

Using Google Chrome, my JavaScript files are linked properly, if I click on them in the source, they load the file correctly.

Below that you can see in my dev tools that the JS files do not show up at all in the Resources list!  And as such, I cannot access JavaScript  files, you'll notice the undefined error for jQuery.

As far as I know, JavaScript is enabled in my browser and works on other sites, sometimes I can even get some JS to work on this site but when I include JS file, they are not working, none of them!

Such a bizarre issue.  Does anyone have a clue what could be going on here?

[image]

Comment: Where exactly are your files placed?

Comment: @Raphael_ My asset files are all placed in the default `public` directory of laravel

Comment: Did you try linking to the relative path, instead of the absolute one?

Comment: @Raphael_ I currently use Laravel's method like this... `{{ asset('/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js') }}`

Comment: I have tried linking relative and full path and also have tested in Firefox and it has the same issue.  I am thinking it must have something to do with the server but it's very strange as none of my non-laravel apps have this issue.  Also the fact that I can click the link and the file will load in the browser so the links do work

Comment: Is there any error in the console in dev tools?

Comment: @HaoLuo The only error is from inline scripts trying to call jQuery and jQuery not being loaded but nothing else to show there is a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to kick yourself... script tag is src not href :)

Comment: Oh man thank you!  You won't believe how long this has been a problem, at least a few days...I've been working on the PHP side in that time but still!  I think I copy/pasted them in a rush and that's the result